# sending value on partial file via another view and render that form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%@nfo.each do |m|%>

  <table>

    <tr><p class="icons"><%= m.name %></p></tr>
          <tr> <%= image_tag  m.picture(:big)%><tr>

       <%@a -=1%>
   </div>

</table>
<% end %>
```

when I am using this at that time I can iterate it through each but I want to iterate it on another view file for that I made it some thing like

```
<%@nfo[i].name%>

  <table>

    <tr><p class="icons"><%= @info[i].name %></p></tr>
          <tr> <%= image_tag  @info[i].picture(:big)%><tr>


   </div>

</table>
```

and in another view I am rendring this form and want to pass the value of i but I am not able to pass how I can pass the value because now this form also giving error i is not define is it possible to send the value from one view to partial file like this

Answer (score 1):

You can pass variables to your partial:

```
<%= render :partial => "your_partial", :locals => { :variable => value } %>
```

Then you can access those in your partial through the locals hash. Therefore you just pass the variable in your view.

Comment: ya through this variable i can send the value in view file at the time of using the loop thanks i it solved my probleam

Comment: first in the main view file in variable "value" i take the m as a object in your code it is a variable and i  send the object "m" in your code variable to partial file which change in every loop . So i got one more thing that through object we can send value in other view .thanks

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure what you are trying to say. Was that another question? Are trying to pass variables through multiple views?

Comment: I was trying to explain how did i implemented  in my program . thanks

Comment: Allright :-) You can now click the hook to accept the answer.